# Image taken with custom camera using surfaceview on android 4.0 powered devices(like Galaxy s3) is showing less resolution

Tags: android, camera, android-camera, surfaceview

I am developing an app, in that I am using Surfaceview and Camera api to take picture. My problem is the resolution of Image taken using Galaxy S3 is showing only 640x480. But in other devices it is showing the resolution as per the camera. Because of this when I display the Image it is coming blurred, only in S3, In other devices it is displayed perfectly.

I don't know what is the problem behind this. Other devices are running on 2.3 and s3 is on 4.0. Please help me.

Comment: have you check the resolution for image capture of camera in s3 ?

Comment: no, how can I check it...(anyway S3 camera must be having more resolution than 640x480)

Comment: not sure, but might be its been set to lowest resolution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different devices have different resolutions available.

You can find what picture sizes are supported when you set the camera in your class that extends Surfaceview:

```
public void setCamera(Camera camera) {
    this.mCamera = camera;
    if (mCamera != null) {
        List<Camera.Size> mSupportedPictureSizes = Camera.getParameters().getSupportedPictureSizes();
        //Iterate over list and find the size you want.
        Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
        parameters.setPictureSize(chosenPictureSize.width, chosenPictureSize.height);
        mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
    }

}
```